# How to write cURL request with basic auth in Laravel 8

Tags: php, authentication, curl, paypal, laravel-8

I have the following code from PayPal Payout SDK to get access tokens from the PayPal API.

```
curl -v POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "CLIENT_ID:SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

To get the access token, I have tried the following.

```php
$client_id = "AWN5555";
$secret = "44444";
$url = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
$data = ['grant_type:client_credentials'];

$response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Accept:application/json',
    'Accept-Language:en_US',
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
])->withBasicAuth($client_id, $secret)
    ->post($url, $data);

// OR

$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
        'Authorization ' => ' Basic ' .
            base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $secret)
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

laravel 7 or 8 solution :

```
$client_id = "AWN5555";
$secret = "44444";
$url = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
$data = [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        ];

        $response =  Http::asForm()
                            ->withBasicAuth($client_id, $secret)
                            ->post($url, $data);
```

php native solution :

```
$client_id = "AWN5555";
$secret = "44444";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($client_id.':'.$secret)
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```